# how to add multiple values to a custom label and check if string exist or not

Tags: apex, customlabel

I have more than 1 string values which I would like to store to a custom label and write if condition to see if the string value exist in custom label or not.

for example : is it possible to add "Car, Truck" to a custom label and then in the if condition we can check whether the custom label contains "Bike" or not and do the rest of the process in if loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign your label value to string and then check if string contains your value

```
string str = system.label.test;
system.debug('>>>.. '+str);
if(str.contains('Bike')){
    system.debug('>>It has bike');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot write to custom labels through Apex.  However, it sounds like what you are actually looking for is a custom text field, in which case it's fairly easy to do what you are asking.  Pretend I've added a field called `Vehicles__c` to the object, with a default value of blank:

```
public void addVehicle(string vehicle)
{
    myObject.Vehicles__c = String.isBlank(myObject.Vehicles__c) ? vehicle : myObject.Vehicles__c + ', ' + vehicle;
}

public boolean containsVehicle(string vehicle)
{
    return myObject.Vehicles__c.contains(vehicle);
}

public void test()
{
    addVehicle('car');
    addVehicle('truck');
    if (containsVehicle('bike'))
    {
         //do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

Based on your comment, the answer is that you can retrieve custom labels in Apex using `System.Label.Label_Name` (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm&language=en).  In your case though, my guess is that you'll actually want a [custom setting](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm&language=en4), since you can just add or remove settings and treat them like a list.

As a label, you would need to modify the label string whenever you wanted to add or remove a value:

```
public void test()
{
    List<String> myVehicles = System.Label.MyLabel__c.Split(', ');
    for (String i : myVehicles)
    {
        if (i == 'bike')
           //do something
    }
}
```

On the other hand, a custom setting naturally is a collection of records, which easily translates into a list.  On top of that, you can add whatever other information you want to each record.  For example:

```
public void test()
{
    for (Vehicle__c vehicle : Vehicle__c.getAll())
    {
        if (vehicle.Name == 'bike')
        {
            System.debug(vehicle.MPH__c);
        }
    }
 }
```

Alternatively, if what you are asking is whether you can write code as the value of some field and execute it, there are a few solutions.  Doing this with Javascript on a Visualforce page should be pretty simple, just use:

```
<script>
    eval('{!myObject.javascript_field__c}');
</script>
```

On the other hand, executing a string as Apex code is a bit more involved, you can look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/57416/12831) for an explanation of how to do it through the Tooling API.

If this is what you are planning on doing, be **very careful** if users are allowed to modify the code evaluated in any way.

Comment: So what I am trying to do here is make the code data driven. For example tomorrow if a new string comes, I just have to add it to the label and code will work as is. Os there an option we can compare a string and check if it is in label? I want to remove hard coding values and make the code data driven somehow.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible.For example,create a customlabel with name:
vehicle and value 'Car,Truck'

In the code do the following,

```
set<string> vehicleSet = new set<string>();
supportPartners.addall(Label.vehicle.split(','))
If(vehicleSet.contains('Car'))
{
//your logic here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you could accomplish the required comparison with the stored comma separated values in a **Custom Label**. Apex code below assumes the Custom Label stores the required values as a comma separated text for e.g. Car,Bus

```
List<String> vehicleList = System.Label.Vehicles.split(',');

if(vehicleList != null){

    if(vehicleList.contains('Bike')){

       //Your logic to execute if a match found goes here
    }
}
```