# Get Boolean result by String expression in APEX

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, boolean

I have a string conditions logic that retrieves values for a `Map<String,Boolean>` and checks if logic is true or false.
For example my logic looks like:

**((1A2)O3)**

Being **A** => AND and **O** => OR.

And my map has this kind of structure:

`new Map<String,Boolean>{'1'=>true,'2'=>false,'3'=>true};`

Is it possible to replace characters in logic conditions with boolean values and get a proper result in Apex?
Or even in Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer of your question:

No even if you replace complete String with actual expression there is no way you can parse it. **For parsing the expression you would need to write the parser**.

### Write Parser:

You are actually evaluating expression and **expressions are evaluated using Stack** (generally).

Basically here you would need to build a `stack` where you will put each character in stack and then start popping those characters until you find a matching closing bracket, by that way you can calculate it with much less complexity.

Go through [this algo](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-evaluation/) for more detail.

It is already discussed in [this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/how-to-eval-string-expression-in-salesforce), more [easier solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/57416/20721) could be using the executeAnonymous API although i have never implemented this myself. Refer Daniel Ballinger's [this blog post](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/adding-eval-support-to-apex.html) for more details.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example? Cause I'm pretty lost with this... Thanks in advance!

Comment: @molinet I have added some links which provides more ways of doing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand it better and managed to achieve the requirement.