# Is it possible to evaluate a Salesforce formula in Apex?

Tags: apex, formula, custom-metadata

I want to do something dynamic with an Apex method. I have some custom metadata records that contain an object and field definition. I want to inject the field value from the object into a custom formula (the formula would be stored on the custom metadata record as well, as text) at run-time.

The goal is to allow the custom metadata record to be as configurable as possible without requiring changes to the Apex implementation.

The formula body would look something like this: `YEAR({!field-value}) < {!custom-metadata date field}` and the merge fields would be injected in the Apex method before evaluating the formula as a whole.

psuedo-code:

```
if field value is not null and a date:
  put merge values into formula
  evaluate formula

  if formula is TRUE:
    do foo()
```

**Is it possible to do anything like this in Apex?**

Comment: There are tricks to evaluate Strings in Apex, but that has security implications. Why don't you do the other way around? Create a formula field that depends on custom metadata records and configure the custom metadata records when needed?https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_formula_fields.htm&type=5

Comment: The problem I run into with formulas is that I can't create one on a custom metadata record. So I would need to place formulas on any and all objects that this formula would need to be evaluated on and that would defeat the purpose of using custom metadata with object and field definition references in the first place.

Comment: I think you are trying to rewrite SF a little bit :) So you want something that is set declaratively and can be used for every object and also in apex, that is the definition of a formula field.

Comment: Then there's no native way of doing that, you'll have to do your own parsing. Some things that people have created are http://iandrosov.github.io/APEX-Expression-Eval/ or https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/how-to-eval-string-expression-in-salesforce

Comment: Have you tried this? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Formula.htm If you define the formula as Alba mentioned, this could do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the feedback received in the comments and finding this Salesforce Idea: [Evaluate Dynamic Formula with Apex](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003VESQA2), I've concluded what I want to do is **not possible in Apex**. There seems to be [some libraries](https://github.com/PropicSignifi/Script.apex) and [examples](https://iandrosov.github.io/APEX-Expression-Eval/) of building custom interpreters/expression evaluators out there, however.

**EDIT February 19, 2024**: As of the Spring '24 release, there is a new [developer preview to allow evaluating dynamic formulas in Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_formulaeval.htm&release=248&type=5) using [`FormulaEval`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_namespace_formulaeval.htm?q=formulaeval). If this makes it out of preview, I'll update this answer as this will have been delivered.

Example code from the release notes:

```java
global class MotorYacht {
   global Integer lengthInYards;
   global Integer numOfGuestCabins;
   global String name;
   global Account owner;
}

MotorYacht aBoat = new MotorYacht();
aBoat.lengthInYards = 52; 
aBoat.numOfGuestCabins = 4;
aBoat.name = 'RV Foo';
FormulaEval.FormulaInstance isItSuper = FormulaEval.FormulaBuilder.builder()
                            .withReturnType(FormulaEval.FormulaReturnType.STRING)
                            .withType(MotorYacht.class)
                            .withFormula('IF(lengthInYards < 100, "Not Super", "Super")')
                            .build();
isItSuper.evaluate(aBoat); //=> "Not Super"
```

Comment: This feature is in Developer Preview in Spring '24. Not generally available yet, so @nbrown's answer still holds true for now. Check out the Salesforce Idea page for more details: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdi25UAB

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I didn't know that had made it to preview. That's an exciting new feature!